# rounding with frndint in Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, att

I am trying to pass a float n into ebx (or if I can, just use n) and round it, then pass it back into n and return the value to main, this block of code runs 4 times, each time it is being passed a different roundingMode value, which modifies the rounding count bits of the FPU control word.

The problem is that no matter what I pass it it doesn't round anything. I checked the IA-32 manual and it says FRNDINT rounds the first item in the stack, which is why I am pushing ebx onto the stack.

when I run my code in GDB I can see that at the frndint command it puts crazy values into ebx.

For example, when n = 5.6, FRNDINT puts  2.72008302e+23 into ebx.

```
    asm("   push    %%ebx                           \n"
        "   fstcw   %[trueCWIn]                     \n"     //store FPU CW into trueCW
        "   mov     %[nIn], %%ebx                   \n"
        "   mov     %[trueCWOut], %%eax             \n"
        "   add     %[roundingModeOut], %%eax       \n"
        "   frndint                                 \n"     //do rounding calculation
        "   fldcw   %[trueCWIn]                     \n"     //restoring the FPU CW to normal
        "   pop     %%ebx                           \n"

        :   [trueCWOut]     "=m"    (trueCW),
            [tempCWOut]     "=m"    (tempCW),
            [maskOut]       "=m"    (mask),
            [tempVarOut]    "=m"    (tempVar),
            [roundingModeOut]       "=m"    (roundingMode),
            [nOut]          "=m"    (n)

        :   [trueCWIn]      "m"     (trueCW),
            [tempCWIn]      "m"     (tempCW),
            [maskIn]        "m"     (mask),
            [tempVarIn]     "m"     (tempVar),
            [roundingModeIn]        "m"     (roundingMode),
            [nIn]           "m"     (n)
        :"eax", "ebx"
    );
return n;
```

Comment: The FPU stack is the internal memory of the FPU (aka registers) It's another thing than normal stack and to be accessed in another way.

Comment: does frndint use the FPU stack or the normal stack? this is the quote from the IA-32 manual: "Rounds the source value in the ST(0) register to the nearest integral value, depending on the
current rounding mode (setting of the RC field of the FPU control word), and stores the result
in ST(0)." it doesn't specify normal stack vs FPU stack, so I assume it means normal stack.

Comment: The FPU does't know anything about the normal stack. If the term "stack" is used relating to a FPU instruction it is always the FPU stack. Read IA-32 manual Vol. 1 Chapter 8, or better a tutorial: http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/

Comment: the only FPU related instruction I have that comes before frndint is fstcw, which as far as I can tell doesn't do anything with the FPU stack.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. Which is why your code doesn't work. By way of illustration, if you just wanted to round using the current rounding mode, you could do something like: asm("frndint" : "+t" (n)); To understand what "+t" does, check out the "Intel 386" section on gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html for 't' and look at gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html for the '+'. The remainder of the problem is left as an exercise for the student. Which is what I assume you are. FWIW, I solved this with 4 lines of asm, 3 params, 0 clobbers. You may be overthinking it a bit.